# How to animate a radial gradient smoothly using keyframes

Tags: html, css, animation

I have this background pattern. But my code just skips to the end. I want a smooth animation from big to small circles.

```css
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#363636 10px, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  animation: loaderout 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes loaderout {
  100% {
     background-image: radial-gradient(#363636 0.7px, transparent 1px);
    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS variables and `@property` with a fallback for the Firefox browser since there is no support for `@property` yet

```css
@property --d {
  syntax: "<length>";
  initial-value: 0px;
  inherits: true;
}

.loader {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#363636 var(--d), transparent 1px);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  animation: loaderout 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes loaderout {
  0% {--d: 10px;}
  to {--d: 0px;}
}

@supports (-moz-appearance: none) {
  .loader {
    --d: 1em;
  }
  @keyframes loaderout {
    0% {font-size: 10px;}
    to {font-size: 0px;}
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
```